# How can I look and search for a key inside a heavily nested hash?

Tags: perl

I am trying to check if a BIG hash has any keys from small hash and see if they exist, and if they do modify the BigHash with updated values from small hash.

So the lookup hash would look like this :

```
configure =(
    CommonParameter => {
        'SibSendOverride' => 'true',
        'SibOverrideEnabledFlag' => 'true',
        'SiPosition' => '8',
        'Period' => '11'
    }
)
```

But the BigHash is very very nested.. The key/hash `CommonParameter` from the small hash `configure` is there in the BigHash.

Can somebody help/suggest some ideas for me please?

Here is an example BigHash :

```
%BigHash = (

'SibConfig' => {
                'CELL' => {
                            'Sib9' => {
                                        'HnbName' => 'HnbName',
                                        'CommonParameter' => {
                                                                'SibSendOverride' => 'false',
                                                                'SibMaskOverrideEnabledFlag' => 'false',
                                                                'SiPosition' => '0',
                                                                'Period' => '8'
                                                         }
                                 }
                          }
                },
)
```

I hope I was clear in my question. Trying to modify values of heavily nested BigHash based on Lookup Hash if those keys exist.

Can somebody help me? I am not approaching this in the right way. Is there a neat little key lookup fucntion or something available perhaps?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. How about you show what the hash should be after the change?

Comment: Are you saying that there is a hash *somewhere* in the data structure that has the key `CommonParameter`? Is it guaranteed that there is only one such hash element?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. My hash `%configure` from my above example which has updated values for `CommonParameter`. `%BigHash` has the sub-hash `%CommonParameter` too, but it is not updated yet. My objective is, to check if `%BigHash` has keys of `%configure`, and if it does, then update `%BigHash` with values from `%configure`.

Answer (score 2):

Give [`Data::Search`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aSearch) a try.

```
use Data::Search;
@results = Data::Search::datasearch(
   data => $BigHash, search => 'keys',
   find => 'CommonParameter',
   return => 'hashcontainer');

foreach $result (@results) {
    # result is a hashref that has 'CommonParameter' as a key
    if ($result->{CommonParameter}{AnotherKey} ne $AnotherValue) {
        print STDERR "AnotherKey was ", $result->{CommonParameter}{AnotherKey},
             " ... fixing\n";
        $result->{CommonParameter}{AnotherKey} = $AnotherValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could describe what interpretation of the question you have chosen, and what your answer does

Comment: This answer finds a hash key in an arbitrarily complex data structure and makes the embedded hash references that contain that key available for further manipulation.